# How to set the Status of an entity to modified for a context derivin from ApplicationDBContex?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm using an assembly (dll) that contain my `Context` class, this class holds both the identity tables and my own tables:

```
namespace SharedModels
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext();

        public DbSet<UserTask> Tasks { get; set; }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create();
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

I can't change the code in it, but I need to set an entity (from `Tasks` table) to modified, but I can't find the `Entry` method on that context:
[image]

<s>apparently it doesn't inherit from `DBContext` class, is there a way to accomplish this?</s>

Comment: It [does derive from DbContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn468176(v=vs.108).aspx) though

Comment: @IvanStoev but why doesn't it has `Entry` method? (please, see the screenshot I added to the question)

Comment: I don't know, it might be just Intellisense issue.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I should add a reference to: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;

I couldn't find this without distrusting the Intellisense:

[image]